# Can I copy TokenPrivileges array from one computer to another?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm writing a logging service that may collect privileges of a process for the purpose of transmitting it to another computer. I use the following code to collect it:

```
HANDLE hToken;
if(OpenProcessToken(::GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
{
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    if(!GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenPrivileges, NULL, dwSize, &dwSize) &&
        ::GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    {
        BYTE* pb = new (std::nothrow) BYTE[dwSize];
        if(pb)
        {
            TOKEN_PRIVILEGES* pTPs = (TOKEN_PRIVILEGES*)pb;
            DWORD dwSize2;
            if(GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenPrivileges, pTPs, dwSize, &dwSize2) &&
                dwSize2 <= dwSize)
            {
                //Got our BYTE array in 'pb' of size 'dwSize2' bytes
                memcpy(pByteArrayToTransmit, pb, dwSize2);

            }

            delete[] pb;
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hToken);
}
```

But I'm curious, if I could pass the `pByteArrayToTransmit` array to another Windows computer and be able to convert it into a readable form using [LookupPrivilegeName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379176%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API?

PS. The reason I'm not calling `LookupPrivilegeName` on the client machine (where the data is being logged) is to save on the size of the logged data, since this process may repeat many times over.

Comment: Note that you can compress the data in the obvious way, down to a single byte since there are less than 256 privilege names. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Oh wow, and they allotted 64-bits for that?

Comment: Probably just for alignment reasons.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Thanks. Appreciate your take on it! Just from your experience though, have you ever seen MS using values for these privileges that are outside of that short one-byte boundary?

Comment: I've never had occasion to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation for LookupPrivilegeValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The LookupPrivilegeValue function retrieves the locally unique identifier (LUID) used on a specified system to locally represent the specified privilege name.

That strongly suggests that the LUIDs are different on each system.  At the very least, there is no guarantee that they will be the same.

*Addendum*

Assuming that the logging system does not absolutely have to work under every conceivable circumstance, and assuming that the logs will be analyzed in software and that you can update the analysis software every time a new version of Windows comes out, and provided the logs also include the Windows version, it should be safe enough to compress this information into a single 64-bit bitmap as Eryksun suggests in the comments.

If you want to play it as safe as possible, I suggest a bitmap followed by an optional variable-length field.  You can have a fixed table of strings (one for each privilege name that we know about) with one bit in the bitmap for each string.  If all the privilege names you see are in the table, the bitmap is all you need.

If you see one or more privilege names you didn't know about, set the top bit in the bitmap to indicate that there is more data, then add one or more null-terminated strings, with an additional null at the end to indicate the end of the list.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was thrown off by as well. But why do they define them, as @sutol suggested in his answer?

Comment: @c00000fd, for example, [`SeMachineAccountPrivilege`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc234327) is currently privilege number 6. It was [added in NT 3.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc234419#id38). Before that in NT 3.1, privilege 6 was [`SeUnsolicitedInputPrivilege`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff556652) (obsolete). That's actually still the global symbol name in the kernel, i.e. in a kernel debugger you can execute `dd nt!SeUnsolicitedInputPrivilege l1` to confirm that the value is 6.

Comment: @c00000fd, the `*_PRIVILEGE` defines are in the DDK at an API level, not as a stable ABI. Per the above, Microsoft reserves the right to re-purpose obsolete privileges, so you need to be aware of this for forward-compatibility if the client machine is a newer release. BTW, the SDK only has the `*_NAME` defines, which makes it pretty clear Microsoft does not want user-mode applications referencing privileges by number.

Comment: @eryksun: Thanks. Also to quote Harry, `...function retrieves the locally unique identifier...` Do they seriously imply that, for instance, `SE_CREATE_TOKEN_PRIVILEGE` or `2` is a `"locally unique"` ID :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `2` as a *locally* unique ID. ;-) It looks like logon providers were supposed to be able to extend the well-known privileges. It's just another `LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES` value in the token's `PRIVILEGE_SET`, so `NtPrivilegeCheck` shouldn't care. But I don't think this was ever implemented. I tried adding privilege `42` via `LsaAddPrivilegesToAccount`. It succeeds for well-known privilege values such as `SE_CREATE_SYMBOLIC_LINK_PRIVILEGE`, but trying to add `42` returns `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

Comment: @eryksun: you could try using a legitimately generated LUID, i.e., AllocateLocallyUniqueId(), although since according to the docs those are only unique until a reboot that probably wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I just checked in kd in Windows 7 to confirm a suspicion. The `TOKEN.privileges` field is now an `SEP_TOKEN_PRIVILEGES`, which has 3 64-bit bitmaps for `Present`, `Enabled` and `EnabledByDefault` privileges. The original design that used an `LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES` array of privileges was apparently abandoned; I guess after they never got around to implementing the ability to load privilege sets. Using a bitmap is optimized, but limited.

Comment: `AllocateLocallyUniqueId` makes the system call `NtAllocateLocallyUniqueId`, which increments a global 64-bit value at `nt!ExpLuid` by `nt!ExpLuidIncrement`, which is just 1. I assume the initial value is well beyond the range of statically assigned well-known LUID values on the system, such as privilege values.

Comment: @eryksun: yeah, I thought perhaps real LUIDs would have bit 31 or bit 63 set to distinguish them from well-known values.  Then functions like LsaAddPrivilegesToAccount() might check that bit, and if it isn't set, only allow assigned well-known values, so as to stop people from using custom values that might later be assigned.  But since the LSA privilege database is persistent, using a counter that gets reset on reboot wouldn't be a very good idea. :-)

Comment: It looks like the only place generated LUIDs are used is as ID numbers for logon sessions and tokens.

Comment: Anyway, since the current `TOKEN` definition is limited to privilege numbers in the range `[2,63]`, @c00000fd can create a bitmap like `SEP_TOKEN_PRIVILEGES`, but prepend a field that has the OS version. The latter will enable handling breaking changes (e.g. privilege number assignments and the bitmap sizes) in future versions of Windows.

Comment: `SEP_TOKEN_PRIVILEGES` is actually 3 bitmaps, which accounts form privileges that are present (but not necessarily enabled), enabled, and enabled by default. I like the idea of using the (otherwise unused) initial bit to signal an unknown/remapped privilege. You can call `LsaEnumeratePrivileges` to prebuild the system table, and flag privileges that are unknown or have an unexpected value.

Comment: @eryksun: if you're being cautious, you would want to avoid LsaEnumeratePrivileges, since it isn't documented.  Besides, we don't need to log the existence of unrecognized privileges unless they are actually present in the token(s) we're examining.  Safest to just call LookupPrivilegeName() for each privilege in the token, then search for it in a fixed string table and build the bitmap and (if necessary) extra strings from that.  (The table doesn't even need to be in any particular order; our bitmap doesn't have to match the one Windows uses, after all.)

Comment: I was just looking to make it more efficient using a pre-computed table. You could call `LookupPrivilegeValue` instead to build a table ordered by privilege value that maps to the bitmap index. Then if a privilege value is mapped to the default value of 0 in the pre-computed table, enable the bit 0 flag and call `LookupPrivilegeName` to get the string to append.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean - use the privilege value to determine which name you're expecting, rather than having to search the entire string table each time for a match.  Yeah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do this. privilege values is invariant.

```
#define SE_MIN_WELL_KNOWN_PRIVILEGE         (2L)
#define SE_CREATE_TOKEN_PRIVILEGE           (2L)
#define SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_PRIVILEGE     (3L)
#define SE_LOCK_MEMORY_PRIVILEGE            (4L)
#define SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_PRIVILEGE         (5L)

#define SE_MACHINE_ACCOUNT_PRIVILEGE        (6L)
#define SE_TCB_PRIVILEGE                    (7L)
#define SE_SECURITY_PRIVILEGE               (8L)
#define SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_PRIVILEGE         (9L)
#define SE_LOAD_DRIVER_PRIVILEGE            (10L)
#define SE_SYSTEM_PROFILE_PRIVILEGE         (11L)
#define SE_SYSTEMTIME_PRIVILEGE             (12L)
#define SE_PROF_SINGLE_PROCESS_PRIVILEGE    (13L)
#define SE_INC_BASE_PRIORITY_PRIVILEGE      (14L)
#define SE_CREATE_PAGEFILE_PRIVILEGE        (15L)
#define SE_CREATE_PERMANENT_PRIVILEGE       (16L)
#define SE_BACKUP_PRIVILEGE                 (17L)
#define SE_RESTORE_PRIVILEGE                (18L)
#define SE_SHUTDOWN_PRIVILEGE               (19L)
#define SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE                  (20L)
#define SE_AUDIT_PRIVILEGE                  (21L)
#define SE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PRIVILEGE     (22L)
#define SE_CHANGE_NOTIFY_PRIVILEGE          (23L)
#define SE_REMOTE_SHUTDOWN_PRIVILEGE        (24L)
#define SE_UNDOCK_PRIVILEGE                 (25L)
#define SE_SYNC_AGENT_PRIVILEGE             (26L)
#define SE_ENABLE_DELEGATION_PRIVILEGE      (27L)
#define SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_PRIVILEGE          (28L)
#define SE_IMPERSONATE_PRIVILEGE            (29L)
#define SE_CREATE_GLOBAL_PRIVILEGE          (30L)
#define SE_TRUSTED_CREDMAN_ACCESS_PRIVILEGE (31L)
#define SE_RELABEL_PRIVILEGE                (32L)
#define SE_INC_WORKING_SET_PRIVILEGE        (33L)
#define SE_TIME_ZONE_PRIVILEGE              (34L)
#define SE_CREATE_SYMBOLIC_LINK_PRIVILEGE   (35L)
#define SE_MAX_WELL_KNOWN_PRIVILEGE         (SE_CREATE_SYMBOLIC_LINK_PRIVILEGE)
```

Comment: References, please.  These definitions don't appear in *my* copy of the SDK. :-)

Comment: this from <wdm.h> . however all this constants for privileges not changed from win 2000(and early) up to win10. and this of course absolutely independent from client machine

Comment: Oh, the DDK.  No guarantee those values will be the same ones visible to a user-mode application, then, although I don't suppose there's any particular reason why MS would bother obfuscating them.  Probably safe enough for logging purposes, so long as you also record the OS version.  (I wouldn't want to depend on it for anything essential.)

Comment: The other curious thing about that is the reference to well known privileges, which implies that there might be privileges that are *not* well known, but vary from machine to machine.  My guess is that this was just something they thought they might need to do one day, but never have.

Comment: "No guarantee those values will be the same ones visible to a user-mode application"
delirium. this is value which stored in token. and no any different from what mode (kernel or user) will be query.
this is constant and unchanged.

Comment: " but vary from machine to machine. " this is invariant

Comment: This is not really guaranteed to be invariant across kernel releases. However, I could only find the one example where the meaning of a privilege number changed, i.e.  from `SeUnsolicitedInputPrivilege` (NT 3.1) to `SeMachineAccountPrivilege` (NT 3.5), and that was only because the former was dropped as obsolete.

Comment: @sutol: well, can *you* find any documentation saying that the LUID presented to user-mode applications will be the ones listed in the DDK?  Also, *by definition,* a privilege which is not well-known will vary from machine to machine - that's what "not well-known" means!  As far as I know, Windows doesn't support such privileges, but the implication that it might is curious.

Comment: "can you find any documentation saying that the LUID presented to user-mode applications will be the ones listed in the DDK"
what i say based not on documentation, but on 10+ years experience working with this

Comment: "This is not really guaranteed to be invariant across kernel releases"
from windows 2000 how minimum, up to latest win10 this value not changing, but extended - added new values.

Comment: Yes, and that's fine, but all I said was that there was no guarantee.  Microsoft would be perfectly within their rights to release an update tomorrow that added 42 to the LUIDs presented to user-mode applications.  They're not going to, but they *could*.  IMO, it is important for a programmer to keep in mind that using the numbers rather than the names is unsupported, no matter how unlikely it seems that they would ever change.

Comment: no different user or not user mode. this values is common to token. for PRIVILEGE_SET structure. call you GetTokenInformation or ZwQueryInformationToken no different. call you ZwQueryInformationToken from user or kernel mode - no different. and however this is common and great mistake think that DDK(WDK) - for kernel mode only. all this is very usable from user mode too :)

Comment: @HarryJohnston, Microsoft would be perfectly within their rights to randomly reorder these values. If you're using the API properly, then you'll never know the difference. Not that they'd do this. One could also imagine a new privilege being added for, say, Windows 11, and then made obsolete and replaced with a different privilege in Windows 12. Now you have a client that says privilege X is enabled, and you'll need to know the client OS version and track the changes so you don't confuse this with privilege Y.

Comment: Usable, yes.  Supported, no.

Comment: of course can be theoretically any chanches and replaces in this values, however no any reason do this. can be added new privelege values to the and of array - so list will be extended, but already existing not changed.
Usable, yes. Supported, no.
dont know, what is mean under Supported. i for example include both ntfs.h and windows.h always, use ntdll api much more frequently that kernel32 api and all work great :) so for me this is supported

Comment: @sutol: It's a very stupid design from the MS part (and a waste of CPU cycles to do all these useless conversions from a 64-bit int to string and vice versa) but I agree with Harry Johnston and eryksun that if MS deprecate, IDK, the `SE_SHUTDOWN_PRIVILEGE` and decide to add a new one `SE_MAKE_EVERYONE_LOVE_IE` with the same value `19`, it will create a confusion in software that relies on the shutdown privilege being just value `19`. (And as eryksun suggested above, there was already a precedent with the `SeUnsolicitedInputPrivilege` which makes me wary.)